# Erro de compilação no C++ quando acessa estrutura em função

Tags: c, c++, funções, struct

Estou criando um código que guarda as informações de 3 pessoas dentro de um *struct*, mas estou tendo um erro de compilação quando vou gravar a opção da idade no `struct`. O erro é este:

> ```
> /home/arthur/Área de Trabalho/pj/pj.cpp: In function ‘void 
> cadastrar()’:
> /home/arthur/Área de Trabalho/pj/pj.cpp:42:17: error: ‘pessoas’ was 
> not declared in this scope
>  //  scanf("%d",&pessoas[i].idade);
>
>              ^~~~~~~
> ```

E o código é este:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#DEFINE MAX_PESSOAS[3]
typedef struct{
  char nome[30];
  char profissao[30];
  int  idade;
  int ativado;
}comp;

void cadastrar();

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  comp pessoas[3];

  int op;
  do{
    printf("\nPara adastrar pessoas aperte 1\n");
    scanf("%d", &op );
    getchar();
    switch (op) {
  case 1:
    cadastrar();
  break;
}
}while(op!=0);
}
void cadastrar(){
  char nome[30];
  char profissao[30];
  int idade;
  int op;
do{
  printf("\nNome: ");
  getchar();
  fgets(nome,sizeof(nome),stdin);
  printf("\nProfissão: ");
  fgets(profissao,sizeof(profissao),stdin);
  printf("\nIdade: ");
  scanf("%d", &idade);
for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  //if (pessoas[i].ativado==0) {
    strcpy(pessoas[i].nome, nome);
    strcpy(pessoas[i].profissao, profissao);
    pessoas[i].idade = idade;
    break;
//  }
}
  printf("\n1 - Continuar\n0 - para sair\n");
  printf("Digite sua escolha: ");
  scanf("%d", &op );
}while (op!=0);

}
```

Comment: a mensagem de erro é clara: a variável "pessoas" não está declarada no lugar ("escopo") onde foi usada...a solução é declarar essa variável

Comment: É isso que não estou entendendo, ela ja não esta declarada embaixo do main?

Comment: Consegui arrumar este erro modificando os meios de declaração do struct.       struct cadastro{
    char nome[30];
    char profissao[30];
    int  idade;
    int ativado;
};

void cadastrar();
struct cadastro pessoas[3];

Comment: @aguiarito Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código tem vários problemas, e dá uma indicação que não entende o que está fazendo. Aprender a programar deve ser passo por passo, aprender assentar cada tijolo para construir a casa toda, querer fazer a casa sem entender cada detalhe não funciona e será atropelado o tempo todo. E cada vez fica mais complicado e mais difícil resolver no futuro. Eu melhorei várias coisas no código, mas ainda tem muitas outras que poderiam ser melhoradas.

Não vi sentido nesse `for` e há muito uso de coisas desnecessárias, mas falta uma fundamental, a variável que guarda os dados na função `cadastrar()`. Como criou isso na `main()` e para um exercício faz sentido tem que passá-la como argumento para a função que faz o cadastro, e claro, a função deve receber isto como parâmetro.

Reforço que não resolvi tudo, apenas melhorei e resolvi o problema descrito.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char nome[31];
    char profissao[31];
    int  idade;
    int ativado;
} Pessoa;

void cadastrar(Pessoa pessoas[3]) {
    int op;
    int i = 0;
    do {
        printf("\nNome: ");
        fgets(pessoas[i].nome, sizeof(pessoas[i].nome), stdin);
        printf("\nProfissão: ");
        fgets(pessoas[i].profissao, sizeof(pessoas[i].profissao), stdin);
        printf("\nIdade: ");
        scanf("%d", &pessoas[i].idade);
        printf("\n1 - Continuar\n0 - para sair\n");
        printf("Digite sua escolha: ");
        scanf("%d", &op);
        i++;
    } while (i < 3 && op != 0);
}

int main() {
    Pessoa pessoas[3];
    int op;
    do {
        printf("\nPara cadastrar pessoas aperte 1\n");
        scanf("%d", &op);
        switch (op) {
        case 1:
            cadastrar(pessoas);
            break;
        }
    } while (op != 0);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Ul5dtz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zuptnbki-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/PassArgument.c).

Answer (score 0):

Melhor uma solução puramente C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Pessoa {
    std::string nome;
    std::string profissao;
    int idade;
    bool ativado;
};

void cadastrar(std::vector<Pessoa>& pessoas)
{
    int op = 0;
    do {
        Pessoa p;
        std::cout << "\nPessoa: ";
        std::cin >> p.nome;

        std::cout << "\nProfissão: ";
        std::cin >> p.profissao;

        std::cout << "\nIdade: ";
        std::cin >> p.idade;

        pessoas.push_back(p);

        std::cout << "\n1 - continuar\n0 - sair\n";
        std::cin >> op;
    } while (op == 1);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Pessoa> pessoas;

    int op;
    do {
        std::cout << "\nPara cadastrar pessoas aperte 1\n 0 - sair\n";
        std::cin >> op;
        if (op == 1) {
            cadastrar(pessoas);
            break;
        }
    } while (op != 0);
}
```